# how to find the first and follow values of grammar

Tags: grammar

i have the following grammar and i would like to create the First & follow table. if i have a case that the first of non terminal is epsilon should i take also all the terminals that came after this non terminal from is rule?

```
S-> ABC
A->Aa/aB
B->Bb/epsilon
C->Cc/epsilon
```

and my question is:
in the first of C i need to get First(C) = {epsilon,c) and First(B) = {epsilon,b)?
i got the following results but still i think i have problems:

```
  |first|follow
S |a    |$
A |a    |a
B |eps,b|b,a,$
C |eps,c|$
```

Comment: FOLLOW(A) also includes FIRST(BC$); since B is nullable, that includes FIRST(B), FIRST(C) and `$`. And why do you think `a` is in FOLLOW(B)? Your FIRST computations are correct, though.

Comment: because B is in the end of A and i know that usually when non terminal is located on the end of rule is follow will be the follow of the first non terminal like in case of A and S

Comment: The tokens in the FOLLOW set for A must be able to follow A.

Comment: so the follow of B should be only b and $ ?

Comment: FOLLOW(B) is FIRST(C$) because the only context in which B can appear is S->ABC$. So it is {c,$}. This should all be covered in your textbook.

Comment: but what about B -> Bb i should not refer to this rule? after your answer does the grammar will be LL(1) because before of that i got is not.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. {b, c, $}.

Answer (score -1):

Finding the FIRST and Follow of a Grammar written in txt FILE:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #define size 10

    int i,j,l,m,n=0,o,p,nv,z=0,x=0;
    char str[size],temp,temp2[size],temp3[20],*ptr;

    struct prod
    {
        char left_of_non_term[size],right_of_nonTerm[size][size],first[size],fol[size];
        int n;
    }pro[size];



    int main()
    {
        FILE *f;

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            pro[i].n=0;

        f=fopen("lab6.txt","r");
        while(!feof(f))
        {
            fscanf(f,"%s",pro[n].left_of_non_term);
            if(n>0)
            {
                if( strcmp(pro[n].left_of_non_term,pro[n-1].left_of_non_term) == 0 )
                {
                    pro[n].left_of_non_term[0]='\0';
                    fscanf(f,"%s",pro[n-1].right_of_nonTerm[pro[n-1].n]);
                    pro[n-1].n++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            fscanf(f,"%s",pro[n].right_of_nonTerm[pro[n].n]);
            pro[n].n++;
            n++;
        }

        printf("\nGiven Grammar");
        printf("\n-------------\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<pro[i].n;j++)
                printf("%s = %s\n",pro[i].left_of_non_term,pro[i].right_of_nonTerm[j]);

        pro[0].first[0]='#';
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<pro[i].n;j++)
            {
                if( pro[i].right_of_nonTerm[j][0]<65 || pro[i].right_of_nonTerm[j][0]>90 )
                {
                    pro[i].first[strlen(pro[i].first)]=pro[i].right_of_nonTerm[j][0];
                }
                else if( pro[i].right_of_nonTerm[j][0]>=65 && pro[i].right_of_nonTerm[j][0]<=90 )
                {
                    temp=pro[i].right_of_nonTerm[j][0];
                    if(temp=='S')
                        pro[i].first[strlen(pro[i].first)]='#';
                    findter();
                }
            }
        }
        printf("-------------");

        printf("\n\nFIRST\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\n%s -> { ",pro[i].left_of_non_term);
            for(j=0;j<strlen(pro[i].first);j++)
            {
                for(l=j-1;l>=0;l--)
                    if(pro[i].first[l]==pro[i].first[j])
                        break;
                if(l==-1)
                    printf("%c ",pro[i].first[j]);
            }
            printf("}");
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            temp2[i]=pro[i].left_of_non_term[0];
        pro[0].fol[0]='$';
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(l=0;l<n;l++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<pro[i].n;j++)
                {
                    ptr=strchr(pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j],temp2[i]);
                    if( ptr )
                    {
                        p=ptr-pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j];
                        if(pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j][p+1]>=65 && pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j][p+1]<=90)
                        {
                            for(o=0;o<n;o++)
                                if(pro[o].left_of_non_term[0]==pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j][p+1])
                                        strcat(pro[i].fol,pro[o].first);
                        }
                        else if(pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j][p+1]=='\0')
                        {
                            temp=pro[l].left_of_non_term[0];
                            if(pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j][p]==temp)
                                continue;
                            if(temp=='S')
                                strcat(pro[i].fol,"$");
                            findfol();
                        }
                        else
                            pro[i].fol[strlen(pro[i].fol)]=pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j][p+1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\n\n\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\nFOLLOW (%s) -> { ",pro[i].left_of_non_term);
            for(j=0;j<strlen(pro[i].fol);j++)
            {
                for(l=j-1;l>=0;l--)
                    if(pro[i].fol[l]==pro[i].fol[j])
                        break;
                if(l==-1)
                    printf("%c",pro[i].fol[j]);
            }
             printf(" }");
        }
        printf("\n");
        //getch();
    }

    void findter()
    {
        int k,t;
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(temp==pro[k].left_of_non_term[0])
            {
                for(t=0;t<pro[k].n;t++)
                {
                    if( pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][0]<65 || pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][0]>90 )
                        pro[i].first[strlen(pro[i].first)]=pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][0];
                    else if( pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][0]>=65 && pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][0]<=90 )
                    {
                        temp=pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][0];
                        if(temp=='S')
                            pro[i].first[strlen(pro[i].first)]='#';
                        findter();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void findfol()
    {
        int k,t,p1,o1,chk;
        char *ptr1;
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            chk=0;
            for(t=0;t<pro[k].n;t++)
            {
                ptr1=strchr(pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t],temp);
                if( ptr1 )
                {
                    p1=ptr1-pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t];
                    if(pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][p1+1]>=65 && pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][p1+1]<=90)
                    {
                        for(o1=0;o1<n;o1++)
                            if(pro[o1].left_of_non_term[0]==pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][p1+1])
                            {
                                    strcat(pro[i].fol,pro[o1].first);
                                    chk++;
                            }
                    }
                    else if(pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t][p1+1]=='\0')
                    {
                        temp=pro[k].left_of_non_term[0];
                        if(pro[l].right_of_nonTerm[j][p]==temp)
                            continue;
                        if(temp=='S')
                            strcat(pro[i].fol,"$");
                        findfol();
                        chk++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pro[i].fol[strlen(pro[i].fol)]=pro[k].right_of_nonTerm[t] 
   [p1+1];
                        chk++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(chk>0)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Also Make a text File named it lab6.txt . and put grammers like below

```
    S ABCDE 
    A a|0
    B b|0
    C c
    D d|0
    E e|0
```

Here space after NonTerminal Indicates the -> this sign and 0 indicates epsilon.